# Meaning of red dot in review drop-down menue

Tags: support

For the first time today, I observed a red dot instead of the usual silver dot on the Review page drop-down menu:

[image]

Also, the review category, "Suggested Edits" is in a bold font, which also is unusual.  Clicking on the category with the red dot first brought up an edit to be reviewed (which I did) but later brought up nothing.  What is the significance of the red dot and bold lettering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does not make sense to copy whole answer so let's get to the point here and read more in meta.se post:

[How does the review-needed indicator work exactly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226/233085)

"Suggested Edits" has a low threshold to light the red dot, 3, and it was hit that day. You may have not seen 3+ cases due to caching issues mentioned in the linked topic.

Why don't we ever see others?, See the threshold table, those numbers, even for small sites are higher that what you usually find in the review. Even the one observed by you will not be so frequent.